# calling getEventArgs() always returns null

Tags: javascript, events, crm, onchange, microsoft-dynamics

MS Dynamics: I have a Javascript code that needs to process the event args of the context. This is my code:

```
 function myFunction(econtext)
{
    var eventArgs = econtext.getEventArgs();
}
```

This function is fired on the OnChange event of a field. 
The problem is that eventArgs variable is ALWAYS null!
Instead getDepth() returns a not null value.
Why does only eventArgs is always null?
I have already set the context as first parameter when I have associated the funtion to the event.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getEventArgs` is available only for the `Save` event, this is the reason you get null inside the `OnChange` event.

From MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg328130.aspx#BKMK_getEventArgs

> This method returns **null** for any event other than the **Save** event.

Comment: Ok thanks! My problem is now the following: the onchange event changes the values of some fields according to the new value of the changed field. But when I Save the page the onchange event is fired again and my logic doesn't work anymore. Is there a way for preventig the Save event from firing the onchenge event? Or a way to understand (inside my Function) that I'm saving the page?

Comment: when you save the onchange event should not be fired again (only the functions attached to the save event will be called), this is the standard behavior. If you have an OnChange event called during the save event, there is something not right with your CRM instance